# Add publisher in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How are you guys ?

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am trying to add a publisher on my server but when I left click on "Replication", I don’t see the option "New Publication". I am following a tutorial but I can’t follow it because I need to enable that option.

Thanks so much

Comment: Which **edition** of SQL Server are you using? Express? Standard? Web? Enterprise?

Comment: I am using Standard

Answer (score 0):

Replication --> Local Publications --> Right Click

Comment: I know the option has to be there but it is NOT.  The software is called MICROSOFT SQL SERVER MANAGMENT STUDIO.

Comment: could you add a screenshot and SSMS version as well?